# Why is my blender file 13GB?

Tags: objects, blend-files, append

I'm somewhat new to Blender and I've been working on a project for the past couple of months. However I've got to the point where the file is practically unable to be opened without crashing (I have an 8 core i9, 32Gb XPS).

Looking at the file size it is almost 13GB, which is way bigger than it should be, from what I've seen. I've appended it and gathered the size of different objects and they all seem to be quite bulky in size.

The project is just a series of objects with some shaders. There are lots of spheres (which have something like 320 vertices) and cylinders. There is also a terrain I generated which is below 100MB.

As I said I'm quite new to Blender and I really can't find why these objects occupy to much file space, stopping me from being able to continue the project.

Comment: Yeah, something seems definitely wrong. I've made some pretty large scenes, filled with 2k and 4k textures, and still barely broke 1GB.

Comment: May be something unecessary packed into the file. Try ro unpack it: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html#unpack-data

Comment: Lots of spheres... How many? Also a terrain... How complex, what size, what size textures? How many vertices in total for the scene?

Comment: There are 106,000,000 vertices, about the same number of faces and 227 objects in total. If someone could put these numbers into perspective, that'd be useful.